# Using AJAX to collect a link from a php page and update image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a php page which spits out a profile picture URL from a instagram account that is supplied. For example if you went..

```
 .com/ajax_check_instagram.php?username=tom
```

the page would return

```
http://instagram.com/profilepic.png
```

I then have an ajax call which im trying to manipulate so the sucess function updates an image source.

```
        //Add a loading image in the span id="availability_status"
        var link = '';
        $.ajax2({  //Make the Ajax Request
            type: "POST",  
            cache: false,
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/ajax_grab_instagram.php",  //file name
            data: "username="+ username,  //data
            success: function(server_response){
                 link = server_response;
                 $("#profilepic").attr("src","link");
            }
          }); 

        }
```

How would I format the server_response line and jquery line?

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP/AJAX file you need to return the URL of the picture. Then in your jQuery AJAX request...

It's pretty much there as is except you have `link` encapsulated within double quotes.

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "POST",  
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/ajax_grab_instagram.php",
    data: "username="+ username,
    success: function(response) {
        $("#profilepic").attr("src",response);
    }
});
```

I have changed it to `response` in my example.

Comment: I thought i was close, it doesnt look like this is actually working for me though:(

Comment: It looks like the server is sending back the link OK but the ajax isnt getting applied?

Comment: Are you echoing the response from the PHP page rather than return?

Answer (score 0):

link is a variable, not a string.

```
$("#profilepic").attr("src", link); // link should not be in quotes
```